# what is the keycodes for the numpad buttons: "/" and "." in regards to the libraries I am using or another library that might not ignore those?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the question states, I have reached an impasse. The keys "/" for divide and "." for decimal on the keypad portion of the standard keyboard simply are not seen by the two methods that I have found to add keyboard functionality in a Chrome Extension I am writing. 
I have tried to gain this using the library here: 
http://suan.github.io/jquery-keycombinator/ and the library here:http://keithamus.github.com/jwerty. The code I am using, which I will paste below, for each works just fine except for those two keys for some unknown reason. I don't know if I'm just doing it wrong or if I'm just missing something, but some clarification to end this dilemma would be so greatly helpful.

Thank you very much!

```
// outputs "print!" to the console when pressed.
jwerty.key('[num-0-num-9]', function () { console.log('numpad number') });
jwerty.key('[0-9]', function () { console.log('regular number') });
//jwerty.key('111', function () { console.log('decimal!') });
jwerty.key('enter', function () { console.log('enter!') });
jwerty.key('+', function () { console.log('plus!') });
jwerty.key('-', function () { console.log('minus!') });
jwerty.key('*', function () { console.log('multiply!') });
//jwerty.key('110', function () { console.log('divide!') });
jwerty.key('shift+9', function () { console.log('(!') });
jwerty.key('shift+0', function () { console.log(')!') });
```

The "110" and "111" are just one of the many attempts to catch the right thing. I know it is wrong.

```
//button catcher -- keyboard
$(document)
.makeKeyCombinator(
{
    onComplete: function(keyComboData)
    {
        $(".temp").html('<pre class="prettyprint">' + 
JSON.stringify(keyComboData, null, 2) + '</pre>');

        var keys = ExtractKeys(JSON.stringify(keyComboData, null, 2));

        $(".temp").append('<pre class="prettyprint">' + JSON.stringify(keys, 
null, 2) + '</pre>');
    }
});
```

Being that I'm using two completely different libraries, the solution is most probably simple stupid, but again, I would greatly appreciate any help any of you can provide toward this end.

Answer (score 2):

Following are the key codes for your expected keys

"/"  = **191** |  For numpad : **111**

"."  =  **190** |  For numpad : **110**

Ref : http://keycode.info/

Comment: I appreciate greatly your input but the valies: 111 and 110 were already known asstated in the first code snippet I posted. To clarify what I was after is the question why neither of those buttons were registered by either of the libraries I was attempting to use, and how I might could capture those keydown events. Again, your input is greatly appreciated but doesn't precisely answer my question. Thank you.